# Proving an Intuitive Result Rigorously

Tags: calculus, limits

I have found that for distinct functions (not constants) $f(x),g(x),h(x)$ that this is true:
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(x)g(x)}{f(x)g(x)+h(x)}=1$$ I want to know: why is that, ie is there a rigorous proof for why that is? Maybe a paper to turn to or is it really simple?

**EDIT:** I realized I probably should have put my actual problem first. I hope this gives more context. For this limit:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{e^{H(n)}\log H(n)}{e^\gamma n\log(\gamma+\log n)+\frac{n}{\log\log n}}$$
$H(n)$ tends to $e^\gamma n$, which is the same as $\gamma + \log n$. So, you can reword it as this:
 $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{e^{\gamma + \log n}\log(\gamma + \log n)}{(\gamma + \log n)\log(\gamma+\log n)+\frac{n}{\log\log n}}$$
So how do you continue to prove  that this limit is $1$?

Comment: It seems that you are assuming that $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{h(x)}{f(x)g(x)}=0$$ for all functions $f$, $g$, $h$.

Comment: Ok, I have a specific limit in mid, let me pull it up.

Comment: Ok, I edited my question.

Comment: @QuoteDave Perhaps you should ask a new question; with your edit, your question becomes quite different from what you originally asked.

Comment: $\mathrm{e}^\gamma n \neq \gamma + \ln n$.  In particular, try $\gamma = 0$, $n = 1$.  What is true is that $\mathrm{e}^\gamma n = \mathrm{e}^{\gamma + \ln n}$ for $n > 0$.

Comment: Ok, should I delete this question?

Comment: No $\gamma$ is Euler's constant.

Comment: @QuoteDave : Does not matter.

Comment: Oh, whoops, made a mistake, again.

Comment: @QuoteDave It's up to you whether you think the question is worth deleting. What I can suggest is that the limit of $f/(f+h)$ is $1$ if the limit of $h/f$ is zero, as Peter pointed out (I just replaced $f \cdot g$ by $f$).

Comment: Ok, thank you. @Sambo

Comment: Apparently, I can not delete this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many continuous nonconstant functions whose limit is zero.  For instance, using three of these, let $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{x}$, $g(x) = \mathrm{e}^{-x}$, and $h(x) = 1+ \dfrac{\sin x}{x}$ so that 
$$  \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x)g(x)}{f(x)g(x) + h(x)} = \frac{0 \cdot 0}{0 \cdot 0 + 1} = 0  \text{.}  $$

---

Anticipating where your edit is going.  Use the manipulation
$$  \frac{f}{f+\frac{n}{\ln \ln n}} = \frac{f}{f+\frac{n}{\ln \ln n}} \cdot \frac{\, \frac{1}{f} \,}{\frac{1}{f}} = \frac{1}{1 + \frac{n}{f \ln \ln n}}  \text{.}  $$
Since your $f$ grows slightly faster than linearly in $n$, you get $\dfrac{1}{1+0}$ as your limit.

Comment: Ok, I edited my question.

Answer (score 6):

If $f(x)=x$, $g(x)=x^2$, and $h(x)=x^4$, then$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)g(x)}{f(x)g(x)+h(x)}=0.$$So, the statement is false.

Comment: I changed it to include non-constants.

Comment: And I've edited my answer.

Comment: Ok, I edited my question.

Comment: How can someone answer your question if you keep changing it?

Answer (score 5):

This statement is false as pointed out by Jose.

For example, if I pick $h(x) = f(x)g(x) $, then

$$  \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x) g(x)}{ f(x) g(x) + f(x) g(x)} = \frac{1}{2} $$

no matter if you have constant or not, it will always be $\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

This is not true in general. For example, if $f$, $g$, and $h$ are all the constant function that maps to $1$, the limit is $1/2$. If you want distinct functions, take $f=1, g=2, h=3$ uniformly to see that the limit is $2/5\neq 1$.

On the other hand, if $h$ is $o(fg)$ and $fg$ is nonzero, then $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x) g(x)}{f(x)g(x) + h(x)} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{1 + h(x) / (f(x)g(x))} = 1. $$

In that situation $fg$ is nonzero, the above argument says that the limit is one if and only if $h = o(fg)$.

Comment: Ok, I edited my question.